# update from angular 2 to 4, but not successful

Tags: angular

I have updated my project from angular 2 to 4.

I ran:

```
npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest 
@angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest 
@angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-
browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest 
@angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save
```

and then I have the following problem:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/angular2-platform-node/node-platform.d.ts:1:10
TS2305: Module ‘”C:/angular/node_modules//platform-browser”‘ has no exported member ‘AnimationDriver’.
```

Can somebody tell me, what I should do?

Comment: which is your node version. Verify that you are running at least node 6.9.x and npm 3.x.x by running node -v and npm -v

Comment: Hi Hareesh, I have checked by running npm -v, it is 3.10.10

Answer (score 0):

Please delete node_module folder and then follow these commands. It will automatically upgrade your angular 2 to angular 4 +.

npm i -g npm-check-updates

npm-check-updates -u

npm install